# Is it possible to obtain the inequality $\|\nabla f\|_{L^{2p}} \leq C (\|f\|_{L^\infty} \|f\|_{W^{2, p}})^{1/2}$ from interpolation/harmonic analysis?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde, interpolation-spaces

Nirenberg's paper [*On elliptic PDEs*](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=ASNSP_1959_3_13_2_115_0) claims that if a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ tends to zero at infinity or is in $L^q$ for any $q < \infty$ then the "interpolation" inequality
$$
\lVert∇ f \rVert_{L^{2p}} ≤ C \left(\lVert f\rVert_{L^\infty} \lVert ∇^2 f \rVert_{L^p}\right)^{1/2} 
$$
holds (theorem on p. 125).
This is proved by establishing the inequality
$$
    \lVert∇ f \rVert_{L^{q}} ≤ C \left(\lVert f\rVert_{L^r} \lVert ∇^2 f \rVert_{L^p}\right)^{1/2} \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
(equation (2.5) in the proof of that theorem)
for any $1 < r,p < \infty$ and $\frac{2}{q} = \frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{p}$ with a constant $C$ **independent of $r, p$**, and the taking the limit $r \to \infty$.
I haven't really looked at Nirenberg's proof, but as far as I can see it is "calculus-based".

On the other hand inequality \eqref{1} looks like the interpolation inequality
$$
\lVert f \rVert_{W^{1,q}} ≤ C_{p, r} \left(\lVert f\rVert_{L^r} \lVert f \rVert_{W^{p, 2}}\right)^{1/2} \label{2}\tag{2}
$$
for $1 < r, p < \infty$ and $q$ as above,
that you get by using harmonic analysis (the Mihlin multiplier theorem and the Littlewood--Paley characterization of Sobolev spaces, to be precise) to establish that $W^{1,q}$ is the $\frac{1}{2}$-interpolation space between $W^{2,p}$ and $W^{0,r} = L^r$ (e.g. Bergh--Löfström, *An introduction to interpolation spaces*, Thm 6.4.5).

Is there some way to get \eqref{1} using the same methods as for \eqref{2} (maybe only with $\lVert f \rVert_{W^{p,2}}$ on the RHS instead of $\lVert ∇^2 f \rVert_{L^p}$), but with the constant independent of $p, r$, so that you can conclude the case $r = \infty$?

Or even better, is there some way to modify the interpolation arguments to give the $r = \infty$ case directly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a Littlewood-Paley + interpolation style proof.  If $P_k$ denotes a Littlewood-Paley projection to frequencies $|\xi| \sim 2^k$, then the standard Littlewood-Paley characterisations of Sobolev spaces give
$$ \| \nabla f \|_{L^{2p}} \sim \| (\sum_k 2^{2k} |P_k f|^2)^{1/2} \|_{L^{2p}}$$
and
$$ \| \nabla^2 f \|_{L^{p}} \sim \| (\sum_k 2^{4k} |P_k f|^2)^{1/2} \|_{L^{p}}$$
while
$$ \| \sup_k |P_k f| \|_{L^\infty} \lesssim \|f\|_{L^\infty}$$
so by Holder's inequality it suffices to establish the pointwise bound
$$ (\sum_k 2^{2k} |P_k f(x)|^2)^{1/2}
\lesssim A(x)^{1/2} B(x)^{1/2}$$
where
$$ A(x) := (\sum_k 2^{4k} |P_k f(x)|^2)^{1/2}$$
and
$$ B(x) := \sup_k |P_k f(x)|.$$
In fact we have the stronger estimate
$$ 
{\sum_k 2^{k} |P_k f(x)| \lesssim A(x)^{1/2} B(x)^{1/2}} \label{3} \tag{$\ast$}
$$
since from the triangle inequality we have
$$ \sum_{k \leq k_0} 2^{k} |P_k f(x)| \lesssim 2^{k_0} B(x)$$
and from Cauchy-Schwarz we have
$$ \sum_{k > k_0} 2^{k} |P_k f(x)| \lesssim 2^{-k_0} A(x)$$
and the claim follows by optimising in $k_0$.  (The estimate \eqref{3} also likely follows from some interpolation lemma on weighted $\ell^p$ spaces in Bergh-Lofstrom, but I don't have the reference handy.)

This argument in fact shows that we can replace the $W^{1,p}$ norm by the slightly stronger Triebel-Lizorkin norm $F^{1,p}_1$ if desired.

Comment: How do you estimate $\left( \sum_k 2^{2k} |P_k f(x)|^2 \right)^{1/2}$ by $\sum_k 2^{2k} |P_k f(x)|$? Don't the weight mess things up at low frequencies (i.e.\ if $|P_k f(x)| = δ_{k k_0}$ then the former is $2^{k_0}$ and the latter is $2^{2k_0}$)?

Comment: In any case, can you also get the bound on $\left( \sum_k 2^{2k} |P_kf(x)|^2 \right)^{1/2}$ directly from $\sum_{k ≤ k_0} 2^{2k} |P_k f(x)|^2 ≲ 2^{2k_0} B(x)^2$ and $\sum_{k > k_0} 2^{2k} |P_k f(x)|^2 ≤ 2^{-2k_0}\sum_{k > k_0} 2^{4k} |P_k f(x)|^2 = 2^{-2k_0} A(x)^2$?

Comment: Oops, there were some extraneous factors of 2 that I have now deleted.

Answer (score 9):

I know this direct proof which works also for $\infty$. Assume $2/q=1/p+1/r$ and $q \geq 2$. Then
$$
\int|D_ku|^q=\int D_k u D_k u |D_k u|^{q-2}=-(q-1)\int u|D_k u|^{q-2} D_{kk}u \leq (q-1)\int |u||D_k u|^{q-2} |D_{kk}u|.
$$
Since $(1-2/q)+1/p+1/r=1$ and $q \geq 2$, by Holder inequality
$$
\int |D_k u|^q \leq (q-1)\|u\|_p \left (\int|D_k u|^q\right )^{1-2/q} \|D_{kk}u\|_r
$$
which gives $\|D_k u\|_q \leq \sqrt{q-1}\|u\|_p^{1/2}\|D_{kk}u\|_r^{1/2}$. If $q=2r$, then $p=\infty$ and you get the inequality (with $p$ and $r$ interchanged).

Comment: Incidentally: this proof is basically also indicated in Evans' PDE textbook, as problem 9 and problem 10 in the Sobolev Space chapter.  (I only remember because I assigned it for students in last Spring.)

Comment: @WillieWong True, I just checked it now. I copied the proff above from my old notes but I do not remember the source.